# TCP connection for HTTP request objects hosted on different web servers

Tags: http, networking, tcp

Suppose that you have a persistent TCP connection to web server A and you first make a request for the basic html page. Then after receiving the HTML page, you make requests for the objects inside the html page. We are assuming that the objects we make the request to are all hosted on server A, hence there is no problem using the same TCP connection.

What if however, one of the objects is hosted by another server B? Eg. Third party ads. Would there be a TCP connection established to server B ? Im not so familiar with HTML but correct me if i am wrong !

Answer (score 1):

Yes,your browser makes new connections to the servers hosting parts of your web page. You can observe this e.g. by opening developer tools in Firefox and opening the network tab.

Comment: If server A received 4 requests( excluding the basic html page) to server A and the third request contains the reference to server B's ads, if pipelining were used in this case, it would be possible for the third party add to be loaded earlier than the 1st and second request since the third requests involves a TCP connection to another server ?